# How to enable hot reload for vite react JSX project insteed of refreshing whole page

Tags: reactjs, vite

Whenever I make some changes in my jsx file whole page gets reloaded and saved states vanishes, but I don't want this behavior instead of this i would like to have hot reload just like create-react-app

Comment: vite should have HMR on by default. What is your current setup? Did you create your react app with `npm create vite@latest` or `yarn create vite`? Try creating a fresh app and see if hot reload works.

Answer (score 2):

Ohh ! actually I named react component componentName.jsx that's why
renaming it to ComponentName.jsx resolved it.

If you are rendering your component using JSX, the name of that component has to begin with a capital letter otherwise React will throw an error as unrecognized tag. This convention is because only HTML elements and SVG tags can begin with a lowercase letter.